# How to scroll to an anchor in react-native-render-html

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-render-html

### Problem

I get some html from an *api* endpoint. This html contains internal links like this: `<a href="#my-item" />` which should scroll to `<a id="my-item" href="#">My Item</a>` when clicked.

My problem is that the default behavior for rendered links in [react-native-render-html](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/content/anchors) is this:

> By default, pressing an anchor will open the link in the system browser. This is done with React Native ​Linking API.

That is not the desired behavior, I want it it auto-scroll to the correct tag.

### Code

How can I accomplish this? I have specified a custom `onPress` function for `<a/>` tags, but how can program the default browser behavior?

```
  const renderersProps = {
    a: { onPress: handleLink },
  };
```